# Why are my bullet points for moderncv, fontspec, fontawesome not working correctly?

Tags: fontspec, moderncv, fontawesome

On overleaf, my CV looks fine, but when I use TexShop, the name is misaligned and the bullet points have [regular] next to them.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}      

\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 
\nopagenumbers{}                                  

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{import}
\voffset = -20pt
\textheight = 900pt
% personal data
\name{First}{Last}
\address{}

  
\newcommand*{\customcventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l} 
    {\bfseries #4}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill% move it to the right
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
     {\bfseries #5}
  \end{tabular} \\
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l} 
    {\itshape #3}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill% move it to the right
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
     {\itshape #2}
  \end{tabular}
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\newcommand*{\customcvproject}[4][.25em]{
%   \vfill\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l} 
    {\bfseries #2}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill% move it to the right
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
     {\itshape #3}
  \end{tabular}
  \ifx&#4&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#4%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
\vspace*{-23mm}
\begin{center}
\faEnvelopeO\enspace email@outlook.com \quad
\small
\faMobile\enspace 04-0000-000 \quad
\small 
\faGithub \enspace \href{https://github.com/git-hub}{\underline{github.com/git-hub}}\quad
\small
\faLinkedinSquare \enspace \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/linked-in/}{\underline{linkedin.com/in/linked-in}}
\end{center}

\begin{spacing}{1.1}
\section{EDUCATION}
{\customcventry{Graduated: Nov 2023}{Some program)}{University}{}{}{}}
{\begin{itemize}
  \item Relevant Coursework: stuff
\end{itemize}
}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\end{spacing}
\section{WORK EXPERIENCE}
\customcventry{July-Oct 2023}{Intern}{Company}{Place,state}{}
{\begin{itemize}
  \item stuff
  \item more stuff
\end{itemize}
}\vspace{-11pt}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Load `fontawesome5` instead of `fontawesome`.